# AngularJs input Week - Show current CalendarWeek / Add 10 days to Current Calender Week

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date

I am quite new to Angular and facing some problems atm.

Here is what I want to build:

1. I want to show the current Date: yyyy-MM-ss  **(Works)**
2. I want to show the current Calendar Week: yyyy-Www  **(Doesn't Work)**
3. On button ng-click, I want to add 10 days to todays date. **(Works only for 1)**

CODE: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/SebastianH4/pnufjaha/13/)

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
<div>
    DateToday<br>
    <input type="date" placeholder="yyyy-MM-dd" value="{{today | date :'yyyy-MM-dd'}}"><br><br>

    CalendarWeek:<br>
    <input type="week" placeholder="YYYY-W##" value="{{today | date :'yyyy-Www'}}"/><br><br>

    <input ng-click="add10Days()" value="Add 10 Days" type="button"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JS/AngularJS:**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function MyCtrl($scope) {

$scope.today = new Date();

$scope.add10Days = function () {
      var numberOfDaysToAdd = 10;
      $scope.today.setDate($scope.today.getDate() + numberOfDaysToAdd);
  }; 
});
```

I think it has something todo with the week format yyyy-w## or maybe with the browser (Chrome) I am using. Help would be much appreciated :)

Thanks

Comment: Which version of Angular are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2. 'ww' date filter only works in Angular 1.3 and on. I see you're on 1.0.1
3. Seems to work fine in the fiddle. GIF below:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the hint! Now both calendar fields are actually showing the date. But there is another problem. It keeps on adding 10 days to the new date. But I only want to add 10 days to today's date.. So for example: today is 20.12.2015 .. after clicking the button add10days it should be 30.12.2015. But when I click again it is 09.10.2016. This shouldnt be. Any ideas what i am missing?

Comment: @MarcJohnson it seems to work fine in the fiddle. I just added a GIF in my answer to show it. Are you sure this isn't expected behavior?

Comment: No problem, @MarcJohnson - don't forget to mark it solved :-) Have a great new year!